# difference between component and custom user control

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I am working on a project with some other developers and I notice that they created a custom component to create a readonly implementation of a combobox.  But what is the difference between a component and a custom user control?

Why not use a custom user control for something like that?

Comment: isn't there a property on combobox to do this anyway?

Comment: DropDownStyle = DropDownList ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Component` is the base class of all of controls. You've to derive your control from `Component` When you don't need any user interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1dk63b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use IComponent to implement components that **have no UI**, still you'd like to be able to manipulate instances on a design surface (such as Visual Studio). System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker is one example.

Why your colleagues would implement a ComboBox (a Control with UI, I suppose) I couldn't say - why don't you ask them?